# What suggested supplemental income opportunities exist for a 70 year old Canadian retiree?

Tags: canada, retirement, self-employment, income

This is similar to the question "[Extra revenue for retiree receiving a basic public pension](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/32163/extra-revenue-for-retiree-receiving-a-basic-public-pension)", but focusing not on whether, but what.

I am wondering what forms of supplemental income (jobs/gigs) would you recommend for a retiree receiving social security in Canada, about 70y.o.

The individual was an **independent financial planner** in Canada for about 15 years (investments, insurance, taxation - he knows it), but the business has been all but wrapped up, partly due to conscious choice based on tax considerations, where taxation on the extra income made it not worthwhile. The work would be part-time and relatively low-pressure/stress/effort, not a 9-6 stable/professional type occupation, but something that would bring in a few extra bucks now and then.

**If you have personal experience, or have worked with or observed individuals of such age doing things "on the side" where one doesn't have to sit in a cubicle all day but has some flexibility around hours/days, and flexible time off, would be open to your ideas.**

**Demographic details:** (for the record, this is not me) The person is a first-generation but well-adjusted immigrant, with foreign PHD scientific education, well proficient in English with excellent writing/translating skills.

The person is computer-literate to the point where he can add content to a basic website using template, but nothing too Web 2.0-ish detail-oriented like design, social media integration or SEO. The person has encyclopaedic-type knowledge in the hard sciences, especially physics, and a brilliant inventive mind.

The person is in excellent overall physical health (for a 70 y.o.) so could work from home or in some other location (can drive).

The person has a highly creative engineering/inventive/scientific mind, as well as solid experience in the area of personal and small business financial planning. The need for work comes from somewhat unfortunate life circumstances (e.g. divorce and some unwise financial sacrifices) that left him with only subsistence income at this point in life.

Comment: Howdy @Aymor,   I expect that your question will end up getting closed as being "primarily opinion based".   The format of the site works really well for objective questions with distinct answers that can be right or wrong.   Your question doesn't really have a right or wrong answer.   You should consider if there are any questions you might have that have distinct answers rather than just brainstorming or soliciting opinions.   Best of luck! - Alex B.

Comment: Noted, will do my best, thanks. I sometimes reply with exact same comment!

Answer (score 2):

My initial thoughts would be an ESL teacher or a private tutor for various subjects would likely be the easiest ones to consider. Possibly there are some people that could use the help in their education that would work well.

Comment: Excellent idea that hasn't occurred to me, will pass it on. Thank you for your input. He will probably grumble that it's not worth it either, but at $25+/hr he might reconsider!

Comment: I could see helping immigrants possibly at a low rate but if he is tutoring people going for Master's or PhD degrees I suspect he may be able to charge a much higher rate possibly.